# Como puedo validar un campo string para que no se pueda repetir

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

hasta ahora solo estoy validando para que el campo no sea nulo, me gustaría validar un campo string para que no se pueda repetir.

```
private boolean validarFormulario() {
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Descripción es obligatorio", "ERROR",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTfPeriodo().getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Periono es obligatorio", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            actoAcademicoVentana.getTfPeriodo().requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTfUnidadAcdemica().getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Unidad Academica es obligatorio", "ERROR",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            actoAcademicoVentana.getTfUnidadAcdemica().requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes enviar el texto que deseas validar a tu función y compararlo con el texto en la vista, en caso de ser igual se mostrara el mensaje de dialogo:

```
private boolean validarFormulario(String texto) {
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().getText().isEmpty() || actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().getText().equals(texto) ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Descripción es obligatorio", "ERROR",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTfPeriodo().getText().isEmpty() || actoAcademicoVentana.getTfPeriodo().getText().equals(texto)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Periono es obligatorio", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            actoAcademicoVentana.getTfPeriodo().requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTfUnidadAcdemica().getText().isEmpty() || actoAcademicoVentana.getTfUnidadAcdemica().getText().equals(texto)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Unidad Academica es obligatorio", "ERROR",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            actoAcademicoVentana.getTfUnidadAcdemica().requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean repeatString(String text1, String text2){
  return text1.equals(text2);
}
```

El siguiente codigo te puede ser util ya que se usa la función equals de la clase String y compara una secuencia de caracteres y devuelve verdadero si coinciden caso contrario falso.

Es la mejor manera de comparar de manera precisa dos datos de tipo String.

Comment: Las respuestas de solo código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**Este es una implementación que hice para, luego solo lo llamo a la hora de guardar, para que cuando apreté el botón me tire el mensaje que ya existe esa descripción**

```
public boolean verificarDescripcion() {
    if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().getText().isEmpty()) {
        actoAcademicoVentana.getLblDescripcion().setVisible(false);
        return false;
    }
    if (lista != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            boolean mismo = (!accion.equals("NUEVO") && periodo.getId() == lista.get(i).getId());
            if (actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().getText().equals(lista.get(i).getDescripcion())
                    && !mismo) {
                actoAcademicoVentana.getLblDescripcion().setVisible(true);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "El acto academico que desea ingresar ya existe. Favor vuelva a ingresar otro dato",
                        "Dato Duplicado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                periodoVentana.getLblDescripcion().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().requestFocus();
                actoAcademicoVentana.getTxtDescripcion().selectAll();
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```